# Logo customization for Google Smart Home Action under development

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I have a Smart Home Action under development (marked with "[test]"). It appears under the list of Google Smart Home Action in my Google Home App. However, the icon is the generic cloud icon even though I uploaded my custom logo in the Action Console->Deploy->Directory Information->Images. How can I update the logo so it will show up next to my under development Smart Home Action (marked with [test])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I update the logo so it will show up next to my under development Smart Home Action (marked with [test])?

This is not currently supported. The directory contents you enter into the Actions console are only populated once the Action has been submitted for review and approved.

If you'd like, you can file a feature request in the [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=655104&template=1284148).